# Safari: How do I show history in a new tab in Safari?

Tags: macos, mac, safari

I find this to be annoying. When I click on "History" -> "Show History", Safari shows the history tab in my current tab and not in a new tab. So let say I was browsing Facebook and then decided to see my history, its opens in the tab that Facebook is opened on and not in a separate tab. Now I have to navigate back (click on Back) to get back to Facebook.

Is there any way I can configure that "Show History" is shown on a different tab in Safari when it opens?

Answer (score 2):

As neither way to access history [from menu or from a toolbar button] allows you to open it in a new tab by the usual method of  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  clicking I'd suggest the best method might just be open it in a manual new tab - 2 keystrokes.

- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>T</kbd>   for new Tab
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Y</kbd>   for History

Apparently, Show History  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Y</kbd>  may not be the same key command in all Languages, but I can only check for UK English...

[image]

Comment: I just wish they made safari more intuitive.

Comment: "⌘Y" does not Show History in the version of Safari I'm using, it's "⌥⌘2".

Comment: Might be different per Language. I added a pic. I'm on UK English.

Answer (score 0):

In `Safari -> Preferences... -> General` set "Homepage" as `history://` and "New tabs open with" as `Homepage`.

[image: Safari Preferences]

Comment: This makes all new tabs to be opened with history. It's not what the OP askes for